# variable from text box won't assign

Tags: variables, python-3.4

I am creating some code for a school project, and for a module I use later on, I need to know what the intensity to end on(end_intensity) is. When the code is run, the end_intensity still comes out as unassigned, this means that the

```
if client_intensity == "High":
```

line is never being run.Can someone please explain why it won't assign .

```
correct = False

end_intensity = "Unassigned"

while correct != True:
        id_search = input("please enter the Client ID of the client you wish to record results for:")
            # open file, with will automatically close it for you
            with open("text_documents/clientIntensity.txt") as f:
                user_found = False
                # loop over every line
                for line in f:
                    client,intensity = line.split(",")
                    if id_search == client:
                        correct = True
                        user_found = True
                        intensity = str (intensity)
                        client_intensity = intensity
                        #assigns which one is the end intensity
                        if intensity ==  'High':
                                end_intensity = 'Moderate'
                        elif intensity == 'Moderate':
                                end_intensity = 'High'
            if user_found == False:
                print("I'm sorry no results we're found for that ID, please try again\n")

print(end_intensity)
```

The text document is in this format:

1. NeQua,High
2. ImKol,Moderate
3. YoTri,Moderate

(I apologize for the numbers for the text document formatting,stack overflow would only let me show it like that)

Any help would be appreciated,Thanks

Ieuan

Comment: Presumably `intensity` is neither `'High'` nor `'Moderate'`  when it hits the `if` statement. Maybe use a `print(intensity)` after the `split` to see what you have. Maybe you need a `strip` -- e.g. `intensity = str(intensity).strip()`.

Comment: I tried that and intensity was displayed as "High"

Comment: `'High '` displays the same as `'High'` -- did you try stripping white space?

Comment: I tried using    client_intensity = intensity.strip() and it worked! thank you fo your help